# Is it possible to force browsers to use a specific cipher suite for all requests from WEBAPI - ASPNETCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working with AspNetCore WebAPI. As it is a Banking Service, I need to allow only specific Cipher suite to the brower. (i.e) I need to force browsers to use all the specified Cipher suite in the WEBAPI Code Request.

It is possible to specify cipher suite to use for all the requests to the WEBAPI.

If Yes, Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the Kestrel server options, should allow you to alter or enforce security on the transport based on your needs.

Comment: Hi Greg, Can you give me any working example to do that? If possible